# how do I install android studio 2.3 to my mac osx 10.6.8?

Tags: android, macos

I have an old mac mini(osx 10.6.8).My laptop was damaged So I need to use it. So i need to install android studio and java in it for development work. But couldnt install java 1.8 and android studo 2.3. I also couldnt find any working older version links for android studio. Is there any way I can do android development in the mentioned setup?

Comment: have you followed this link https://developer.android.com/studio/install.html